# Gulp ignoring input files

Tags: gulp, output

This is my gulpfile:

```
// including plugins
var gulp = require('gulp')
, rename = require('gulp-rename')
, uglify = require("gulp-uglify")
, cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin");

// task css
gulp.task('minify-css', function () {
    gulp.src([
        './www/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        './www/assets/css/admin.css',
        '!./www/assets/css/build.min.css'
    ])
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename('build.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/assets/css'));
});

// task js
gulp.task('minify-js', function () {
    gulp.src([
        './www/assets/js/jquery.min.js',
        './www/assets/js/boostrap.min.js',
        './www/assets/js/vue.min.js',
        './www/assets/js/vue-resource.min.js',
        './www/assets/js/MiniModel.js',
        './www/assets/js/AdminUsers.js',
        '!./www/assets/js/build.min.js'
    ])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename('build.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/assets/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['minify-css', 'minify-js']);
```

After run ./node_modules/.bin/gulp the output is:

1. build.css only has admin.css
2. build.js only has AdminUsers.js

Why is missing a lot of source files on output?

More details:
Ubuntu: 14.10
Node version: v0.10.25
Gulp version: 3.9.1

**UPDATE1**: Im using in index.html like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mini-vue/www/assets/js/build.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var usersmodel = new MiniModel(Vue, 'users', '/mini-vue/www/');
    var adminusers = new AdminUsers(Vue, usersmodel);
    adminusers.reload(1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    minifyJS = require('gulp-minify'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),

gulp.task('minify-js', function() {
  return gulp.src('./www/assets/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(minifyJS())
    .pipe(concat('build.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/assets/js'));
});

gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
  return gulp.src('./www/assets/css/**/*.css')
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(concat('build.min.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/assets/css'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['minify-css', 'minify-js']);
```

Comment: Using your gulpfile, it seems its including all js files, although I got 2 errors: 1. Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery build.min.js:1:5014    ... and 2: ReferenceError: Vue is not defined. I have update the question to show how I'm using those libraries.

Comment: that might be the issue with file sort